# How to solve this error in windows, Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Invalid path:

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, gitlab

This error pops up while cloning or pulling the Git.

```
Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Invalid path:
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the repository and add again.